# Wi-Fi connecting to other networks of the same name

Tags: 14.04, networking, wireless, network-manager

I've been running Ubuntu 14.04 on a macbook air for about a year now, and I've recently been experiencing some strange behavior when it comes to my wireless connection.

Let's assume my wireless network is called `MYHOME123`. Every once in a while, I get a dialog box asking me to input the password to `MYHOME123`, which usually resolves itself when I disconnect and then reconnect back to the same network.

In spite of this, I still find `MYHOME123 1` and `MYHOME123 2` in my drop-down Wi-Fi network menu, and examining the network settings shows that only one of the `MYHOME*` networks has the password I set. All of the others have no password, which I assume is the reason why I could connect to them.

What's even stranger is that this problem is non-existent when I try to connect using a windows or mac os machine, which leads me to believe that it could be an Ubuntu glitch. Has anyone experienced this before? What's the reason behind it?

Comment: I've experienced that.Mostly with my internal card. With the USB wifi card I don't seem to have such issue. Might be a driver problem; can't really add anything else to this question. Try deleting all the connections in Edit Connections menu, restart network-manager with `sudo service network-manager restart` and reconnect to your home network or whatever you're using

Comment: I've already done that. From your comment, it doesn't seem like this is a concern then, but rather just a glitch, if I understand correctly?

Comment: Yeah. Might be netwok manager bug. @chilli555 take a look.  What's your opinion ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a universal problem with WiFi auto-configuration:

It happens under Windows and Ubuntu and seems to happen when a network goes out of range and then comes back.  (Sorry, no experience with fruity variations on the same theme)

*The only time* I **never had this happen** was on a console-only server *without `network-manager` nor `wicd`*, but this was my sole sample so that one could be anecdotal.

Comment: I think the answer is insightful but it does seem anecdotal as you point out. I don't know much about networks so I cannot verify it. In order to be convinced I would like to be able to recreate the problem using your criteria. I would've voted up but I can't with my rep

Comment: I think you missed my point. I didn't mark this as accepted because I don't think it's convincing enough; it could provide a lead, but I need something more concrete; something that I can reproduce, or maybe even a bug report and a discussion about it somewhere. I've done some research and didn't find anything useful, and while your answer is insightful, it's anecdotal. I appreciate it a lot though, thank you! Needless to say, it's not very difficult to conclude that the checkmark is to mark answers as accepted.

Comment: The only anecdotal evidence is the single server.  The rest is based on 15+ years of experience with WiFi...  Empirical, but not anecdotal...  ;-)  :P

Comment: So, if I understand correctly, you are saying that the only time it *did not* happen is on that server, but you've experienced it many times over the past 15 years?

Comment: Yes, that's that I was trying to say in my normal confused and confusing state of mind...  **;-)**

Comment: Emphasis added to make it clearer for the next user finding this answer...  Thanks for the feed-back and acceptance!  ;-)

Comment: You mentioned that it didn't happen in wicd, which adds to my guess that it may be network manager bug

Comment: @Serg: No, I only never had it on a server that **did not have** `wicd` and **did not have** `network-manager`  **;-)**  (more emphasis added, thanks for the feed-back)